# Laravel not inserting into table

Tags: sql, laravel, verification

Basically I need to have a e-mail verification system. For clarity, I will post only needed chunks of code that have impact whatsoever. When user registers, a random 40 string token is generated and sent to them, that code is appended to the route like this:

```
Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'RegisterController@verifyUser');
```

So when user clicks on that link supposedly route should call this:

RegisterController:

```
public function verifyUser($token){

    $verifyUser = new VerifyUser();
    $verifyUser->token = $token;
    $verifyUser->getByToken();
    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $verifyUser->user_id;
    $user->get();
    if(isset($verifyUser)){
        if(!$user->verified){
            $user->updateVerifiedStatus();
            $status = "Uspešno ste verifikovali e-mail adresu. Sada se možete ulogovati";
        } else{
            $status = "Već ste se verifikovali.";
        }
    } else{
        return redirect('/')->with('error', "Vaš e-mail ne postoji");
    }

    return redirect('/')->with('status', $status);

}
```

verify_user is table which has an id of the user, and the token field, and if user is not registered, there will be no instance of that user in the table, therefore -> if(isset($verifyUser)),
also, user table has an 'verified' field, which is a boolean and stores true and false values, therefore -> if(!$user->verified).

And here are models which are used in the above mentioned controller

**VerifyUser**:

```
class VerifyUser
{

    public $user_id;
    public $token;
    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;


    public function getByToken()
    {
        $result =
            DB::table('verify_users')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('token', $this->token)
                ->first();

        return $result;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $result =
            DB::table('verify_users')
                ->insert([
                    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
                    'token'   => $this->token,
                ]);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**User**

```
class User
{

    public function get()
    {
        $result =
            DB::table('users')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('id', $this->id)
                ->first();

        return $result;
    }

    public function updateVerifiedStatus()
    {
        $data = [
            'verified' => true,
        ];

        $result =
            DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $this->id)
                ->update($data);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

So, when I click the link, everything passess, I get the success status, which tells me that $user->updateVerifiedStatus() funct is returned succesfully. But, when I check the table, the field is still false, and is not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Add column to fillable looks like this mass assignment related issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.

Comment: You not using Eloquent models here are you?

Comment: Why your are not using laravel builtin functionality ? You should use Model to do these tasks

Comment: I am using my models. What built in functionality? And no, I am not using eloquent, I know I prolly should.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? You don't need to use Eloquent, however, using it will more than likely make your life a lot easier. If you're not using eloquent then why do you have `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');` in your class?

Comment: I am using 5.4.36

Comment: $this->belongsTo() method should give you an error since this is not defined in your class.

Comment: I tried to learn eloquent and that's why I inserted that chunk of code. As u can see, that is the only instance of it, I am not using it in the controller.

Comment: Read it carefully its not difficult and ask whatever you want.https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Comment: $this->belongsTo() is not making any issues, I will remove it for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I will learn eloquent in the future, however that is not the issue here, the issue is not inserting into table when everything looks fine logically.

Comment: Paste your actual code otherwise its difficult to track the cause

Comment: anyhow if you are using eloquent then do this  `protected $fillable = ['column1', 'column2']; in your model class` Add column names here then you will be able to save data in DB

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I thought it would be better to paste only the functions actually used in this functionallity, but if you think it is better, I certainly can paste whole model.

Comment: It looks like the only time your data should be inserting into your verified users table is in `public function create()`, but I don't see anywhere that's being called.

Comment: No, public function updateVerifiedStatus() is also updating the users table.